# Is it possible to do calculation in Unity interface?

Tags: unity

Is it possible to do maths in unity interface, after hitting the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key ?

Comment: In HUD , you can't , it is Global MENU of your Active Application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if you can do it in the HUD (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-button), but you can do it in the Dash (<kbd>super</kbd>-button) with a scope.

Use these commands to install the Calculator Scope for Unity via terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scopes-packagers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-scope-calculator
```

Here the [OMGUbuntu article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/11/help-test-a-unity-dash-based-calculator/) on `unity-scope-calculator`.